# Does the perfect "faxit" have an optative sense?

Tags: verbs, perfect-tense

A sentence in *Corderii Colloquia* 24,

> ille spiritus bonus faxit.

is translated as:

> May that good spirit grant it.

How does the pf ind come to have an optative sense here?

Comment: Hi, Toothrot. Can you explain the reasoning behind the edit reversals? I'm not quite sure why they seemed controversial to you. Cheers.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer, rolling back your edit was unintended, sorry.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are using the abbreviation? It is less clear and I'm genuinely confused why you are making an issue of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually not indicative, but subjunctive. I know Perseus' morph tool parses it as both indicative and subjunctive, but both [Gildersleeve](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=gildersleeve+faxim&source=bl&ots=hXkdqiFIrJ&sig=JmmtfK2GU5EfZDDJmSmwbN9WNBc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9oszc7vbTAhWBTSYKHSXzAIsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=gildersleeve%20faxim&f=false) and the OLD say it's subjunctive and do not mention anything about it being indicative:

> *faxo, faxim* (where later writers use *fecero, fecerim*)

The normal perfect indicative of *facio* was *feci, fecisti, fecit* (etc.).

Answer (score 7):

*faxim* is (according to one theory) the subjunctive (historically: optative) of the old *s*-aorist; note that Old Latin also had an *s*-future *faxō.* There is a rather convoluted discussion of this in [Sihler §502](https://books.google.com/books?id=tcVTC9XJN-8C&pg=PA558&dq=faxo).